# A generic, model-independent question exists, but I would like to know more about a specific model

Tags: discussion, scope

Here is an example of a question formulated in a pretty general, model-independent way: [How does a remap work? Is it harmful for a car?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41522/how-does-a-remap-work-is-it-harmful-for-a-car)

Several shops claim gains of 25~30% max power for a *very specific motorcycle model* by just ECU remapping. For this particular case, I would like to know more about which parameters they touch and the implications. Would it be appropriate asking such a question?

Comment: You have to learn about how engines work, how fuelling systems work, how fuelling systems are controlled and how fuelling is altered according to ambient conditions, load conditions etc then you can start considering how to change the relevant parameters.

Comment: @SolarMike I have successfully adjusted carburetors from 3.5 to 125cc, and later on inspected and calibrated fuel maps for larger engines. I am not a professional, but studying and learning have never been an issue for me. Yet 30% peak power improvement without any mechanical adjustment looks anything but suspicious. But it is also true that the bike comes with a supercharger, so they are probably allowing much more pressure buildup, consequently adjusting fueling and ignition timings.

Comment: I have adjusted carbs on a 3500cc engine... and can use either the balancing gauge or a tube...

Comment: @SolarMike I have never owned a balancing gauge because my larger engine is equipped with a time-gated MAP sensor so that the idle tuning could be done simply by looking at the PC screen. Pretty neat, but I do not really see how this could be pertinent here.

Comment: You mentioned carbs clearly in your comment so it must therefore be relevant.

Comment: @SolarMike not really: it is hard to find a multi-cylinder configurations at the displacements that I mentioned, and certainly I was never lucky enough to own one.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the basic idea of your question would be on-topic, however, to know which parameters they touch I think pushes this into being too broad for the site. The reason being is "Tuner A" will do it differently than "Tuner B". Are either correct/wrong? Probably not, but the answer to your question is going to be different. And, as many tuners which are out there, there'd be a separate answer for each.

Along those lines, I feel your need for knowledge. The secondary problem is, tuners don't just advertise what they are doing. In other words, it's not common knowledge. If it were, you'd easily be finding it all over the internet. What does this mean? It means, even if you could exactly pin down your question to not be too broad, someone would be hard pressed to find or post an answer.

Comment: I doubt any tuners will want to disseminate their knowledge, that they have spent a long time learning, for free...